# if statement with && and .length

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, operators

I wonder why console says 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' when I combine two if conditions together?

```
//After two if's combined by &&:
for(n= 0, len=i.length; n<len; n++) {
    if(typeof n[i] !== 'string' && n[i].length > longest.length) 
      longest = n[i];
}


// Before I combine two if's:
for(n= 0, len=i.length; n<len; n++) {
    if(typeof n[i] !== 'string') continue;
    if(n[i].length > longest.length) longest = n[i]; 
}
```

Comment: Check your variable naming. You're using `n` like was an array/string and a number at the same time.

Comment: Your two versions are doing totally different things. The first one compares the length if `n[i]` is not a string. The second one does that only if it's a string. But `n[i]` will always be `undefined`, because a number is not an array. I think you meant to use `i[n]`, where `i` is an array potentially containing some strings.

Comment: in first condition what would be n[i].length if n is zero ?

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed out why it was not working, but didn't find the solution because your variable names are not very clear. Maybe this is it:

```js
var i = ['a', 12, 'hello', 'hi', {}, 1.1, 'hey'],
    longest = '';

for(n= 0, len=i.length; n<len; n++) {
    if(typeof i[n] === 'string' && i[n].length > longest.length) longest = i[n];
}

alert('Longest string found: ' + longest);
```

Comment: Actually I mistakenly read !== to === then got confused.... that was a low level mistake. thanks for everyone clarifying it. BTW, can you take a look and see if this solution works too? It might be slower than yours, but I still want to know if it is working as expected. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyWxgN

Comment: @user2734550 the `Array.sort()` method does not return anything, it alters the array it's applied to. So you need to `pop()` afterwards. Also make sure your function name is the same in your function call (wasn't the case). Fixed: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNmYpJ

Comment: Thanks. I had pop() at the end. anyhow, I was just trying to see if there is any odd situation that can cause problems from this way.

Comment: @user2734550 As long as you check that the elements are strings before checking their length, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

n is an integer so n[i] is undefined.

in the last loop: `typeof n[i] !== 'string'` is always true because typeof n[i] equals undefined

but in the first n[i] is undefined so browser throws error when you try to access length property of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I would guess because either `n[i]` is undefined or `longest` is undefined, and `n[i]` is never of string type.

In your first piece of code, you're logical-ANDing the two tests. If my contentions are correct, then the LHS of the `&&` returns true. Although `&&` provides short-circuiting behavior, that does not apply here, because you have `true && ...`, so the `...` must be tested to ascertain the result. Thus, the expression `n[i].length > longest.length` must be evaluated, which is triggering the error.

In your second piece of code, the second test is *never* arrived at, because, as I just speculated, the first test `typeof n[i] !== 'string'` is returning true, so it always runs the `continue;` statement, so it never evaluates the second expression, and you never see the error. But it's still there.

**Edit:** As @OmarElawady insightfully pointed out, you're actually assigning an integer to `n`, and integers cannot be indexed as an array. Thus, `n[i]` is definitely undefined. (`longest` may be undefined as well; we can't tell that from your code.) +1 to @OmarElawady.

Answer (score 0):

The statements are not the same.

First of all, n[i] will never be a string. n is an integer.  typeof n[i] will return 'undefined'.

That said, at the following loop

```
for(n= 0, len=i.length; n<len; n++) {
    if(typeof n[i] !== 'string') continue;
    if(n[i].length > longest.length) longest = n[i]; 
}
```

the first if statement will return true, thus it will `continue` and never reach the second if statement. The result is no error.

On the second loop

```
for(n= 0, len=i.length; n<len; n++) {
 if(typeof n[i] !== 'string' && n[i].length > longest.length) 
 longest = n[i];
}
```

the first condition will return true `(typeof n[i] !== 'string')` 
so as a result, the second condition will be checked.
`n[i]` is undefined because `n` is a integer.

The error `'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'` is correct.